When should welcoming comments be removed?
Recently there has been an increase in the amount of flags asking for removal of comments saying "Welcome to Italian.SE". I have a personal rule of thumb for when to accept those flags, and I know my fellow moderators have others, but I thought it would be better to hear what the community thinks about it.

So, in which cases do you think those comments should be removed?

For reference, this is the best I was able to find as far as SE-wide guidance is concerned.

I remember that, in the past, a new user of this site complained about the fact he/she hadn't received a welcome message in a comment as it is usual in other SE sites. This was more or less the time I decided to begin to write such messages.

@Charo I have never seen new users getting a Welcome comment on other sites. If a user is welcomed, that is done when a comment must be posted for some other reasons. For example, Welcome to Italian Language! Please notice that the question as posted is off-topic for us because […].

Then, what a single user complains about is not a reason to decline a flag that is saying a comment is no longer necessary, considering that in (for example) three years that user had all the time to read the Welcome! comment.

(I should also notice that not receiving any welcome comment is different from receiving a welcome comment that is successively deleted after the user had all the time to read it.)

I'd say that Monica Cellio's answer is a must-have here and I strongly recommend reading her answer, which I fully agree.
Interestingly, that question (over at Meta SE) is exactly about mods posting welcoming comments here, on Italian SE, so that question and this one are actually dupes IMO.
Monica's answer isn't all that comprehensive, but IMO it's straight to the point, so I'll just put my summary here:

Small communities need to grow, when retaining new users is an important role in their growth. And because the easiest way to drive off a new user is to ignore the person, welcoming comments, despite often being found chatty by experienced users, are quite important actually.

Adding to what DaG has answered, such "guidelines" against chatty comments need NOT be enforced consistently across different SE sites. That it works well on SO doesn't mean it will also work well on smaller sites like us (Italian Language).
Oh, and the actual question you're asking about: I think welcoming comments are suitable for deletion after some time, such that most users should either see it or become unlikely to return, say for example, a month or more would be good. And as a consequence of my agreement to Monica's answer, I'm actively against deleting welcoming comments preemptively. Italian SE is a small site and we need new users to feel l'accoglienza we have. (Of course, one is suitable for deletion if there're two - there's usually no need to pile them up)

Actually, the questions are not exactly dupes: the one on [meta.SE] is asking about general SE policy, while this one is asking about the opinion of the [Italian.SE] community. Regardless they are certainly related

Anyway, thanks for your answer! I wasn't aware of that Meta question and of the answer by @MonicaCellio, which seems really interesting to me.

It's up to what ignoring a person on a Q&A site means. To me, it's ignoring a person when the questions asked by that person aren't answered, nobody explains what's wrong in the question, and the questions are down-voted. Posting a Welcome! comment, when it's done "automatically," doesn't seem a way to really welcome a person. Welcoming a person is more about the general behavior toward that person than a single comment.

In my personal opinion, a short, friendly welcome comment does not damage the workings of this website, and contributes to a friendly and encouraging atmosphere.
For a more formal answer, the most upvoted answer (not a rule, but a significant opinion) in the Meta question linked to by the OP essentially says that every SE site does as they see fit, and in particular:

Stack Exchange isn't really homogenous - different communities have different needs to properly engage in their subject matter, and different pressing issues, so Stack Exchange policy enforcement will vary a lot between sites as needed. A site making an active attempt to retain new users, for instance, would see these comments as healthy.

So, I don't see that in StackExchange's rules there is anything against welcome comments.

The tooltip for add comment says: Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”. While there are things that change from site to site, there are things that are constant on every site, such as the purpose of comments and answers. It's not that a site can decide that posting as answer a different, even if related, question is perfectly acceptable.

With that, I do not mean that comments should be avoided, but I find equally "annoying" the idea that a comment suggesting a possible answer should be really made an answer and the idea that a Welcome to Italian Language! comment must be kept forever.
